# How to trigger click input text when click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to automatic click to input text field by using jquery but I need to do it when I click the button. When I click the button cursor will be inside the input text field.

I tried

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#inputtext').focus();
});
```

but it's not working, what is the right code ?

Comment: It works if selectors and markup are relevants

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code above. Are you loading jQuery? Can you provide the relevant HTML please?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded?  Are you getting any errors?  Are you making sure the DOM is loaded first?  If you put a break point inside of the click event, is it getting hit?

Comment: Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/U6W2P/

Comment: `This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.` Thank to you!

Comment: Totally off topic, but we cant help you with what we got here. Take a look a html's ´<label>´ tag. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Answer (score 2):

Look at the console. This code works fine. Make sure it's not something before it: http://jsbin.com/fumoxagu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It works now, thank you. The DOM was not loaded first

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is exactly your problem, but add the following line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the `<head>` and put your code inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('#inputtext').focus();
  });
});
```

I think that either you aren't loading jquery or trying to access elements before it has been created. My solution corrects both.

Comment: It works now, thank you. The DOM was not loaded first